# How to remove dirty flag when editing value in extjs editable grid data?

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs6

An extjs editable grid data grid has the following json data named as

`data.json`

```
{
  "rows" : [ {
    "record_id" : 101,
  }, {
    "record_id" : 102,
    "data" : "",
  }, {
    "record_id" : 103,
    "data" : 62,
  }, {
    "record_id" : "104",
    "data" : "62",
  } ]
}
```

While tabbing through the cells, some data cells show up with a dirty flag. Actually, no any data are changed from the point of users. Here is a demo. Of course, there are data missing, or string, or integer type mixing. The case happens in real life, for user don't care about the programming type, etc. The question is how to clean up the dirty flags, since there is no changed data actually, and while submitting, all of the kind of data do not show up in getChanges()? If any data change happends, such as 62 to 625, it should show up a dirty flag; and if reversing back, such as 625 to 62, it should NOT show up a dirty flag, until a "Save" is clicked.

[image]

Here is the other files related to the test.

`data.html`

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->
<html>
<head>
<meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
<title>Gride Data Testing</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/classic/shared/include-ext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/classic/shared/options-toolbar.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/6.2.0/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="data-ext-0.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="grid-example"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

`data-ext.js`

```
Ext.require([
  'Ext.grid.*',
  'Ext.data.*',
  'Ext.util.*',
  'Ext.state.*' ]);

Ext.onReady(function() {

  var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    // http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/modern/Ext.grid.column.Column.html
    storeId : 'myStore_data',
    autoLoad : true,
    autoDestroy : true,
    proxy : {
      type : 'ajax',
      url : 'data.json',  // the file is defined as the above
      reader : {
        type : 'json',
        keepRawData : true,
        rootProperty : 'rows'
      }
    },
  });

  var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore_data'),
    columnLines : true,
    border : true,
    title : 'Grid Data Testing',
    columns : [ {
      text : "Record ID",
      dataIndex : "record_id",
      width : 200,
      format : '0',
      editor : {
        xtype : 'numberfield',
        allowBlank : true,
        allowNull : true,
      }
    }, {
      text : "Data",
      dataIndex : "data",
      width : 200,
      format : '0',
      editor : {
        xtype : 'numberfield',
        allowBlank : true,
        allowNull : true,
      }
    } ],
    selModel : {
      selType : 'cellmodel'
    },
    height : 230,
    width : 402,
    title : 'Grid Data Testing',
    renderTo : 'grid-example',
    viewConfig : {
      stripeRows : true
    },
    plugins : {
      cellediting : {
        clicksToEdit : 1
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This should be something you handle at the model level. What is the dirty value that's being set?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli javascript data is kind of Duck Typing. model level is somewhat redundancy. The best thing is to implement a task with as less code as possople without losing the clear logic.

Comment: Why should a text field know the difference between `null` and `''`. If you set the value to `null`, then call `getValue`, what should it return? What if you set the value to null, then the user enters a space, then hits backspace? It's a data level concern.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your datas after edit, you can do it on `edit event` of the celleditor plugin like this:

I added a control to commit only if the start and the new value are the same, so the record will not be committed if i change the value in the cell

if the value is null, you need to check also if originalValue and value aren't null

IF YOU DON'T NEED TO COMMIT, you can use this workaround.
the record.set method is not calculated by grid cellediting marker.

```
   cellediting: {
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                listeners: {
                    edit: function (editor, context, e) {
                        if (context.originalValue === context.value ||
                        (!context.originalValue && !context.value)) {
                            context.record.set(context.field,context.value);
                            context.record.set(context.field,context.originalValue);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[here you can see a working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bvn)

The code is updated

Comment: The code migh have a save action, that is not I needed. If any data change happens, such as 62 to 620, it should show up a dirty flag, until "Save" is clicked.

Comment: I'm trying to disable the "dirtyflag" check if value inside cell is null

Comment: Done, please make me know is that's ok

Comment: the answer is promising. However it failed some test cases. 1. fill blank field with data, then remove the data to blank, it shouldn't show up data as dirty. 2. change any data, then reverse back the data, it also  shouldn't show up data as dirty

Comment: the fiddle added "data": "" for "record_id": 101. That means it didn't test on a missing or undefinded data. For "record_id": 104, the data string was changed to integer.

Comment: Your trying to display different types of data on the same column, and you should, whatever, i will try an other solution, remember that you can fix it using the grid without any dirty marker, and adding a class to the interested cell when you need using a cls..